# How to validate a form field inside the validation of different form with JS

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

How to validate a form field inside the validation of different form 
As I have two forms if am i am submitting first form without feeling another form then how can i validate another form in JS. 
Please help me

my code is as below

```
<form action="#" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="return validate()" id="sponsorform1">      
    <input style="margin-left: 25px;" type="image" alt="" name="submit"
      src="http://www.voyage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/sponsor.png" width="250px"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value=""><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="300"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=""><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
</form>
```

my second form is:

```
<form action="#" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="return validate()"
 id="ninja_forms_form_2">      
  <input style="margin-left: 25px;" type="image" alt="" name="submit"
   src="http://www.voyage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/sponsor.png" width="250px"><br>
  <input type="text" name="name" ><br>
  <input type="text" name="surname" ><br>
</form>
```

if i am submitting my first form onclick of image then i must validate my second form.
how can i do this in Javascript???
 please help me....

My Javascript for validation is

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
      alert('hi');
      if (!document.getElementById("ninja_forms_form_2").submit()) {
        alert('Please Fill up the Below Form');
        var x=callme();
        return false;
      }
    }       

    function callme() {
      alert('call');    
     }
</script>
```

As its not showing this alert 'call'
please help as am very new to this .

Comment: you can declare new validate function for form-2 and while submitting form-1, call that new validate function of form-, inside form-1 function

Comment: I did it but not working

Comment: I guess you should post the JS you have so far

Comment: I have posted my code

Comment: Soryy its by fault i forgot to replace that name

Comment: still its not working as my original form is different

Comment: You still have a control named "submit" in **both** forms, so `!document.getElementById("ninja_forms_form_2").submit()` will throw an error.

Comment: Name="submit" in both form for control

Comment: To pass your validation, user can simply turn off JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
        alert(name + " " + surname);
        if((name==null || name == "") 
                && (surname==null || surname=="")){
            alert('Please Fill up the Below Form');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post" target="_top"
        onsubmit="return validate()" id="sponsorform1">
        <input style="margin-left: 25px;" type="image" alt="" name="submit"
            src="http://www.voyage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/sponsor.png"
            width="250px"><br> <input type="hidden" name="cmd"
            value="_xclick"><br> <input type="hidden"
            name="business" value=""><br> <input type="hidden"
            name="no_shipping" value="1"><br> <input type="hidden"
            name="currency_code" value="GBP"><br> <input
            type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"><br> <input
            type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"><br> <input
            type="hidden" name="amount" value="300"><br> <input
            type="hidden" name="item_name" value=""><br> <input
            type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
    </form>






    my second form is



    <form action="#" method="post" target="_top"
        onsubmit="return validate()" id="sponsor">
        <input style="margin-left: 25px;" type="image" alt="" name="submit"
            src="http://www.voyage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/sponsor.png"
            width="250px"><br> <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        <input type="text" id="surname"><br>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I am using `id` attribute instead of `name` for input fields.

Comment: This is My Another Question related to HREF link
Can Anyone tell me how to stop system generated message "EROOR LODING PAGE" 
If i have used 

for(var p=1;p<=numPages;p++)
           {
                var html1='<a class="expensetest" href="' +p+ '" id="clk1"  >' +p+'</a></li>&nbsp&nbsp';//
                $('#expense_list').append(html1);
            
           }
and i have used this href id only but not linked to any page so system is giving that message Error Loading Page how can i stop this message???????
jquery

Comment: To construct the link, try using this
`var html1="<li><a class=\"expensetest\" href=\"" +p+ "\" id=\"clk1\" >" +p+"</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;";`

Comment: I am guessing the `href` is not handled i.e. its not pointing to a proper link.  
Either the `href` should point to a valid link or the user click should be handled by using an `onclick` handler just like `onsubmit`